# Make a deb package that depends on other package installed from deb file

Tags: debian, packaging, dpkg, package-management, dpkg-buildpackage

I am trying to build a deb package A that depends on another deb package B that is downloaded from URL and then installed.

The obvious solution I tried was putting the script that downloads and installs package B in the postinst/preinst scripts of package A.

```
wget package_url
dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

But it gives me an error `dpkg: error: dpkg database lock is locked by another process` because the lock is already locked when installing package A.

How can manage to do this? Is there a way to declare dependencies from the deb URL in the package control file?